# Rules for Full house

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy, poker-tools, full-house

How the full house winner is chosen. Best of five or the card user has?

There was a scenario in a popular mobile app poker, where I had J, 4

On the board J J 4 7 8

I Guess, I have the best combination. But I didn't win.

Winner had 4, 4. What am I missing here?

Comment: Either the app is wrong or you remembered it wrong.

Comment: You indeed should have won